# thunderbird folder pane changed after upgrade from version 17 to 24

Tags: theme, thunderbird

After `Thunderbird` upgrade from version 17 to 24, the "`folder pane`" no longer has my [theme color](http://www.darose.net/Thunderbird-17.0.8.png), but instead has some kind of [light-grey grainy image-gradient](http://www.darose.net/Thunderbird-24.0.png). My `thunderbird` theme is dark, and this is extremely annoying.

[image]

I have found several [links](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/36979) where people complain about this, but no solutions works for me.

Most of these (non-working) solutions involve putting some code into `userContent.css`. What I should put into my `userContent.css` so that I get my old colors back?

I am using Debian Wheezy and my Thunderbird (Icedove) version is 24.4.0

at the moment, my `userContent.css` contains only:

```
span[_moz_quote=true] {
color: rgb(129, 212, 255) ! important;
}
```

## UPDATE:

This seems to be a Thunderbird issue, not related to a theme:

[bugzilla.mozilla.org: Bug 845819](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=845819)

[Folder Pane should have the "sandstone" image overlaid on the background color](http://infinite-josiah.blogspot.ch/2013/02/thunderbird-ui-concept.html)

Comment: Can you please update your Q w/ specific versions of your distro? Also include what theme you're using. It's difficult to debug this further than I did since I have it working fine on several Ubuntu/Debian/Fedora systems and do not see he effect you're referring to. Also can you characterize the issue you're having further? Is it the lightened gray in the folder pane that you're talking about as being the issue?

Comment: @slm - my theme is called Clearlooks. But again, even if I change to another theme, the "folder pane" in Thunderbird still has this gray-sandy-image as background. And yes, the issue is, that I don't like this grey background. I would like to have my dark color back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe this is an actual Thunderbird issue but an issue with Thunderbird and your windowing/desktop environment. I use Thunderbird 24.4 on Fedora 19 with GNOME 3.8.4 and it works correctly.

[image: ss of tb]

#### Other things to try

1. Plugins

   I would also suggest disabling all you plugins to confirm that it isn't an issue being caused by your plugins. You might want to include those in your question too.
2. Re-install

   I'd also try completely un-installing Thunderbird, deleting your profile directory: `$HOME/.thunderbird` and re-installing + recreating your profile to confirm there isn't some residual settings there that are causing this issue.
3. Workaround it using ChromEdit Plus

   You can install the plugin [ChromEdit Plus](http://webdesigns.ms11.net/chromeditp.html) and override the pane's colors in the UI.

   So after you've installed it, open it up from "Tools" -> "ChromEdit Plus" -> "ChromEdit" and in the "userchrome.css" tab, paste in the following code:

   ```
   #folderTree, #listPaneBox {
   background-image: none !important;
   }
   ```

   **NOTE:** This extension allows you to override parts of the UI with CSS.
4. Overriding the background colors

   Using either the plugin ChromeEdit Plus mentioned above or by editing the file located here directly: `$HOME/.thunderbird/<profile>.default/chrome/userChrome.css`:

   ```
   /*
    * * Fix screwed up folderpane in tbird
    * */
   #folderTree, #listPaneBox {
     background-image: none !important;
   }

   /*  Folderpane & Messagepane */
   treechildren {
     background-color: white !important;
   }
   ```

   **NOTE:** You'll want to change the value `white` to whatever's appropriate for your situation.

   [image: ss #2]

#### References

- [Thunderbird UI Concept](http://infinite-josiah.blogspot.com/2013/02/thunderbird-ui-concept.html)
- [FS#36979 - [thunderbird] v24.0 changed folder pane colors](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/36979)

Comment: you can see here, that this is Thunderbird issue: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=845819

Comment: and here, point 6.: "Folder Pane should have the "sandstone" image overlaid on the background color": http://infinite-josiah.blogspot.ch/2013/02/thunderbird-ui-concept.html

Comment: @MartinVegter - that bug is for an older version (22, and was apparently fixed), what makes you think this is the same issue other than they sound similar in description? Also have you tried the suggestions I've provided?

Comment: I have tried installing `ChromEdit Plus`

Comment: I have installed `ChromEdit Plus`. There is no "userchrome.css" tab. There is "Open the chrome Folder" which browses the files that are in my `.icedove/xxxxxx.default/chrome` (i..e `userContent.css`). When I add your code into `userContent.css` there is no effect. Is this addon doing something beyond opening the userContent.css file ?

Comment: When I create a new user on my system, with no themes, with default colors and start Thunderbird, I see the same grey folder-pane - again shows that this is unrelated to my themes. Somebody hardcoded into Thunderbird that "message pane" should be grey for all users.

Comment: @MartinVegter - Good test. I use Thunderbird 24.4 and mine shows the folders alternating colored if you look closely at my screen shot. The overall pane is tinted a light gray, but that tinting get's applied if I change to another theme.

Comment: @MartinVegter - also can you address my comment I left on the Q?

Comment: @MartinVegter - I believe the plugin is facilitating the editing of that file, from what I've read about it.

Comment: @MartinVegter - let me know if the latest update gives you a usable workaround.

Comment: solution 4. works ! Great, I have my colors back. Thank you so much.

Comment: @MartinVegter - that's terrific. A bugger of a problem but we found a solution!